# Creating a heatmap of two different types for d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Absolutely going insane trying to work this out, should have studied harder at school!

I'm wanting to achieve something that I'm convinced is quite simple to do, yet having a hard time understanding the terminology of it all.

I'm wanting to create a heatmap based on a choice of 1 of 2 settings.

First, if I have 5 countries, eg:

1. UK - 10000
2. USA - 5000
3. Brazil - 4000
4. Germany - 1000
5. China - 500

I'm trying to colours based on the ranking.  So for example if I had Red, Yellow, Green, Blue and Purple, then the following would be true:

UK=Red, USA=Yellow, Brazil=Green, Germany=Blue and China=Purple.

Secondly, I want to colour them on value, so in that case the following one apply:

UK=Red, USA=Green, Brazil=Greeny Blue, Germany=Bluey Purple, China=Purple.

But I've absolutely no idea if this is a linear, ordinal, quantile or what-have-you!

I've read the instructions and it looks like the Domain is the input and the Range is the output.

I've got the following code:

```
 var colours = ['#FF0000', '#FFFF00', '#00FF00', '#0000FF', '#FF00FF'];
 var heatmapColour = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, sortedArray.length]).range(colours);
```

And in that example, for the 'Ranking' I'd expect each heatMapColour to return Red, Yellow, Green, Blue and Purple but I get 5 colours ranging from Red (first position) to Yellow (last position).

Any pointers?

edit

As an example, this 'almost works' perfectly.

```
var colours = ['#FF0000', '#FFFF00', '#00FF00', '#0000FF', '#FF00FF'];
var heatmapColour = d3.scale.quantize().domain([0, sortedArray.length-1]).range(colours);
```

If my array has 5 items, it produces the results one colour for each item, but if I have 10 items in my array, I have 2 red, 2 yellows, 2 greens, etc, rather than Red, Red->Orange, Orange->Yellow etc.

Likewise if I have 3 items in the array, I get Red, Green, Purple then nothing.  It makes no sense!

Comment: What's the input value to return the color?  `UK` or `10000`?  If it's numeric does 5000 to 10000, return red and 4000 to 5000 return yellow, etc..?

Comment: Good point.  The array holding the values has just two keys, one is the ISO code that I use as a look up, the 2nd is a value.  The "Rank" heatmap would return Red, Yellow, Green, Blue, Purple as the array will have been sorted.  The "Value" heatmap would have just UK as red, with USA more yellow because it's half the value of UK, therefore in the middle of the colour array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure I understand, but it sounds like you want a quantile scale:

```
var x = d3.scale.quantile()
  .domain([0,500,1000,4000,5000,10000])
  .range(["#FF00FF", "#0000FF", "#00FF00", "#FFFF00", "#FF0000"]);

> x(400)
"#FF00FF"
> x(600)
"#0000FF"
> x(10001)
"#FF0000"
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, wanted to 'play with this as much as possible and can confirm this is as near to perfect what I want.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For this i like to use the RainbowVis.js [https://github.com/anomal/RainbowVis-JS] to map numeric values to colors:

something like this:

```
var rainbow = new Rainbow();
rainbow.setSpectrum('green', 'red');
rainbow.setNumberRange(minValue, maxCalue);
return rainbow.colourAt(CountryValue);
```

You can add more colors to the gradient

Comment: Hey thanks, this could be really handy, will have a look now.